# Custom style on React input of type range

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React component:

```
<input type="range" />
```

I used some css to transform it vertically and it looks like this at the moment:

[image: React slider]

I want to style it so it looks like this:

[image: Styled React slider]

How do I even begin playing around with the circle select and line in the slider?
Do I use some kinds of css pseudo classes? Is it possible to use svg as the circle select?

Answer (score 0):

I might be lazy, but I see 2 possible solutions in order to recreate it, so the axis would be mobile-friendly as well. And personally I would go with the first one.

SVG can be easily created in Figma for example and it will be responsive by itself. You can divide it as three different elements and style it properly, so it would be in right position. Furthermore, SVG can be beautifully animated in GSAP or other libraries of this kind.

The other way, more reduntant in my opinion, would be continuing recreating that purely in CSS with the usage of ::before, ::after and svg icon in the middle, with the additional usage of absolute positioned elements, but it might not be fully responsive in that case.